# Bigquery - Table decorators changed weirdly

Tags: google-bigquery, decorator

I used to have a number of queries running on the past 40 days of data using a decorator with `[dataset.table@-4123456789-]`.
However, since September 15 all the decorators return maximum 10 days of data.

By the way `[dataset.table@0]` returns the whole table and not the past 7 days as told in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators).

Does anyone know what is going on. Do I have to move my table to partition in order to receive data for a limited period of time but more the a week?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious as to how this ever worked. You said "40 days", but decorators can only go back a max of 7 days. So, how did it work with 40 days?

Comment: Decorators worked just fine for big amounts of days back. Since Sep 15 however, maximum last 9 days as shown.

Comment: Decorators have only ever worked for a max of 7 days AFAIK. So, I've no idea how you were going 40 days back.